# Systemd - Unable to run service for filebeat in custom location

Tags: linux, elastic-stack, systemd, filebeat, systemctl

I installed filebeat in a custom location using the linux guide; when I navigate to the folder and run `sudo ./fileabeat -e` it works as expected; when I do it using the service that I'm creating I get below error

```
● fbeat.service - Filebeat sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/fbeat.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-11-24 10:16:00 CST; 12s ago
     Docs: https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat
  Process: 26157 ExecStart=/usr/share/fbeat/filebeat -e (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 26157 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 24 10:16:00 li-250039cc-357d-11b2-a85c-9405a30b5f58.ibm.com systemd[1]: fbeat.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Nov 24 10:16:00 li-250039cc-357d-11b2-a85c-9405a30b5f58.ibm.com systemd[1]: fbeat.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 24 10:16:00 li-250039cc-357d-11b2-a85c-9405a30b5f58.ibm.com systemd[1]: Stopped Filebeat sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch..
Nov 24 10:16:00 li-250039cc-357d-11b2-a85c-9405a30b5f58.ibm.com systemd[1]: fbeat.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 24 10:16:00 li-250039cc-357d-11b2-a85c-9405a30b5f58.ibm.com systemd[1]: fbeat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 24 10:16:00 li-250039cc-357d-11b2-a85c-9405a30b5f58.ibm.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Filebeat sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch..
```

This is how my fbeat.service file looks like

```
[Unit]
Description=Filebeat sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.
Documentation=https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]

ExecStart=/usr/share/fbeat/filebeat -e 
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: So you installed the filebeat executable in /usr/share/fbeat?

Comment: @RamanSailopal yes sir!

Answer (score 2):

As the logs points out, the service is restarting too quickly, the default RestartSec value of 100ms is too short for the service to start.

Try increasing the value to 1 or 2 second.

`RestartSec=1`

It is better if you also assign a user to the service if you want to run it on its own.
assign the username to the User option

`User=<username>`

Here's a [link](https://docs.axway.com/bundle/EmbeddedAnalyticsAPIM_allOS_en_HTML5/page/install_and_configure_filebeat.html)  on how to set it up depending on the init/service manager of your system.